# Why I can see lot more free disk space as root than as a user?

Tags: reboot, disk-space, fsck, midnight-commander, rootkit

When I am logged in as a user, I can see free disk space: 1.2 Gb, with Midnight Commander. Surprisingly when I run "sudo mc" then Midnight Commander shows a lot more free disk space: 1.9 Gb. How is it possible? Should I run fsck on next boot, or do I have a rootkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some filesystems can reserve some disk space for administrators (so that admins have wiggle room in case filesystem gets “full”).  By default for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems, 5% are reserved.

When running as root, Midnight Commander reports the disk space *including* the reserved disk space.

Decision to show one value or the other is made in this line of code: https://repo.or.cz/midnight-commander.git/blob/HEAD:/src/filemanager/mountlist.c#l1516

If you want to know more about this topic, info about the filesystem statistics is available in the `statvfs(3)` man page.

The percentage of reserved disk space for administrators on ext2/ext3/ext4 can be adjusted using `tune2fs`.

Comment: Thx, I also had to run fsck, because after running it I got immediately 1.7 GB free space as a regular user and 2.5 Gb free space as root.